# How to listen for a new message after emit was successful (socket.io on nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, socket.io

I would like to listen again for a new event (`socket.on()`) after the last emit (`io.sockets.emit`) was successful. Because, i got stack-overflow when there are a lot messages arriving (`socket.on()`) to the node server (I think, all the function calls fill up the stack).

Here is the server code (node):

```
const path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //res.status(200).send("Hola mundo");
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('image', function(image){
        io.sockets.emit('image',image);
        return;
    });
});

server.listen(5002, function(){
    console.log("Servidor corriendo en http://localhost:5002");
});
```

This is the client code (python sender-to-server):

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
import base64

print("Conectando...")
socketIO = SocketIO('localhost', 5002)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap_2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
FPS = 23;
print("Conectado.")

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame= cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    socketIO.emit("image",jpg_as_text)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    time.sleep(1/FPS)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And this is the code of the web client side (receiver-from-server):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <img align="middle" width="1100" height="800" id="image">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5002');
        socket.on('image', (data) => {
            const image = document.getElementById('image');
            image.src = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${data}`;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is used for receiving image and sending to a connected client (for video), I know about WebRTC, but, I would like to understand how to manage the functions to avoid stackoverflow. Thank You all for reading.

**Here is the node server complete error**:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[2909:0x55b22e73f140]  1832725 ms: Mark-sweep 2687.3 (2800.0) -> 2687.2 (2800.0) MB, 144.5 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[2909:0x55b22e73f140]  1832872 ms: Mark-sweep 2687.2 (2800.0) -> 2687.2 (2769.0) MB, 147.5 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[2909:0x55b22e73f140]  1833020 ms: Mark-sweep 2687.2 (2769.0) -> 2687.2 (2769.0) MB, 147.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x3a0332198fe1 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */ [/home/estudiante/Downloads/WebSockets_webCam/node_modules/engine.io/lib/socket.js:~359] [pc=0x254b3a412b24](this=0x4a2f0bec79 <Socket map = 0x1c0e8bebeb61>,data=0x3d8ac82d0021 <Very long string[79045]>,options=0x3d8ac82d0139 <Object map = 0x1c0e8bebdb91>,callback=0x3a0332182241 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 2->3
    3: writeToEngine [/home/estudiante/Downlo...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x55b22cfe5011 [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray(int) [node]
 6: 0x55b22cbd1add [node]
 7: v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
 8: 0x254b3a4040bd
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: What does the client do when it gets the `image` event?  You're running out of memory on the server and it doesn't appear you're showing us enough code for us to see why since the server-side code you show doesn't appear to accumulate memory.  So, there must be more going on than you show that is contributing to the problem.

Comment: Uhh, it's hard to help you if you post and then disappear.  Stackoverflow is different than online forums.  Your best chance for help is from people who engage soon after you post.  If you're not around to answer clarifying questions, then you miss opportunities to engage with people trying to help and others see you are being unresponsive and just skip on by.  I'd suggest posting when you can check back multiple times in the next 30-60 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for you recommendation @jfriend00 about my first interaction here. And thank you for your suggestion about the question, I just edited the question and added the web-client-side code, who renders the images when it receives each one.

Answer (score 0):

So your error is not a stack overflow.

It's:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Looking at your code reveals that you are emitting your strings at 23 FPS. Try giving your buffer more time to flush or use binary structures instead of string buffers. Python you can just send bytes Node you can use ArrayBuffers. In the browser you can use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) after you wrap the buffer in a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

But HTMLImageElement is not really meant to be refreshed arbitrarily. So you should just append your client side buffer chunks into a [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource), instead, that is attached to your `video.src`.

Which means that you will have to process your image into a video frame. If your intention was to imitate video streaming. If it's not then just don't refresh at all.